# Dynamic insert procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a dynamic insert procedure. Actually im trying to create all procedures with one button with C#. Anyway, I created that insert procedure but if isActive is null it look like that. So sql server gives an error. Is there any way to replace this coma(,) char? Or any suggestion?

```
INSERT INTO category (  mainCatId,  catname, isActive, ) VALUES (  @mainCatId,  @catname, @isActive,  )
```

It looks like that.

```
declare @mainCatId int = 1, @catname nvarchar (50) = NULL, @isActive bit = NULL

DECLARE @sqlQuery nvarchar(4000); 
SET @sqlQuery =     'INSERT INTO category ( ';

IF ( @mainCatId IS NOT NULL )
 SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' mainCatId, ';

IF ( @isActive IS NOT NULL )
 SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' isActive, ';

SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' )';

SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' VALUES ( ';

IF ( @mainCatId IS NOT NULL )
 SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' @mainCatId, ';

IF ( @catname IS NOT NULL )
 SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' @catname, ';

IF ( @isActive IS NOT NULL )
 SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' @isActive, ';

SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' )';
SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery;
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do this slightly different. Instead of building the string for each value, this have the full SQL statement and you just pass in the values for each of the fields. :

```
declare @mainCatId int = 1, 
    @catname nvarchar (50) = NULL, 
    @isActive bit = NULL

declare @mainCatIdString nvarchar(10)
declare @catnameString nvarchar(50)
declare @isActiveString nvarchar(50) 

DECLARE @sqlQuery nvarchar(4000); 


If @mainCatId is not null
    set @mainCatIdString = cast(@mainCatId as nvarchar(10))
else 
    set @mainCatIdString = ''

If @catname is not null
    set @catnameString = @catname
else 
    set @catnameString = ''

If @isActive is not null
    set @isActiveString = Cast(@isActive as nvarchar(10))
else 
    set @isActiveString = 0

SET @sqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO category 
                (
                    mainCatId, 
                    catname, 
                    isActive
                ) 
                VALUES 
                (
                    ' + @mainCatIdString +',''' 
                        + @catnameString + ''',' 
                        + @isActiveString +')'
 print @sqlQuery
```

Edit: I don't fully see the reason behind using a dynamic query for this. This could easily be performed in a stored procedure similar to this. In this procedure, you will pass all three parameters to it and then evaluate the values based on if they are `null`:

```
create procedure test
(
    @mainCatId int = 1, 
    @catname nvarchar (50) = null, 
    @isActive bit = null
)
AS
BEGIN                               
   INSERT INTO Category
   (
       mainCatId, 
       catname, 
       isActive
   ) 
   SELECT IsNull(@mainCatId, 1), 
      IsNull(@catname, ''), 
      IsNull(@isActive, 0)
END
```

Comment: Good catch but first insert statement is also dynamic and actually it's not up to if else statement. Because for example maybe user use catname or isActive variables so often. So user will send just maincatId and catname. So I dont need to insert isActive variable. Because it can be null. I dont know i am clear or not?

Comment: @kad1r I don't fully understand why you need this to be a dynamic statement in the first place. If you create a stored proc to insert the data, you just pass in the values that you need.

Comment: I have a freelance project that you select your db and it creates all stored procedures dynamically, and i just wanted to do dynamic insert procedure like filtered select procedure like http://pastebin.com/gv3kkSSD. Because i thought maybe this way is better i dont know. Do you have any suggestion? Do i have to do this normal(classical) way?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you bothering to use dynamic SQL at all, and build this query dynamically, leaving out columns that have NULL values? If those columns are nullable, and you want to store `NULL`, why not just say:

```
INSERT dbo.category(mainCatId,catname,isActive) 
  VALUES(@mainCatId,@catname,@isActive);
```

This will put NULL values into the columns where the parameter is NULL. If they are specified as NOT NULL or they have a default, then you can construct the dynamic SQL much simpler:

```
declare @mainCatId int = 1, @catname nvarchar (50) = NULL, @isActive bit = NULL

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000);

SELECT @sql = N'';

SET @sql = N'INSERT dbo.category(mainCatId,catname,isActive) 
  VALUES(' + COALESCE(RTRIM(@mainCatId), 'DEFAULT')
   + ',' + COALESCE(N'''' 
   + REPLACE(@catname, '''', '''''') + '''', 'DEFAULT')
   + ',' + COALESCE(RTRIM(@isActive), 'DEFAULT')
   + ');';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Do you even need to execute this as a sql string?  Can't you just create a stored proc that passes each parameter to it and then you just select those values, similar to what I did in my edit?  Just wondering what would be a better process.

Comment: @bluefeet that would work if you wanted to hard-code the default values. The problem is if the columns are not null with default values, and the defaults later change, now you have to change them in two places. I was giving the benefit of the doubt to the OP that there was a reason this was being done in dynamic SQL in the first place.

Comment: @bluefeet as an aside, I also expected something like this to work, to avoid dynamic SQL, but it does not: `CASE WHEN @mainCatId IS NULL THEN DEFAULT ELSE @mainCatId END`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your exact question, but if you just move the commas, you will not have a trailing comma issue:

I also added quotes for your values (may need to be doubled up again depending of how your dynamic statement is being executed)

```
declare @mainCatId int = 1, @catname nvarchar (50) = NULL, @isActive bit = NULL

DECLARE @sqlQuery nvarchar(4000); 
SET @sqlQuery =     'INSERT INTO category ( ';

IF ( @mainCatId IS NOT NULL )
 SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + 'mainCatId';

IF ( @catname IS NOT NULL )
 SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ',catname ';

IF ( @isActive IS NOT NULL )
 SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ',isActive ';

SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' )';

SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' VALUES ( ';

IF ( @mainCatId IS NOT NULL )
 SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' '''+@mainCatId+''' ';

IF ( @catname IS NOT NULL )
 SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' ,'''+@catname+''' ';

IF ( @isActive IS NOT NULL )
 SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' ,'''+@isActive+''' ';

SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' )';
SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery;
```

Comment: In this situation what will happen if user dont enter mainCatId. It starts with ,catname, isActive. So again problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to strip the trailing character you can put this at the appropriate places in your script:

```
SET @sqlQuery = LEFT(@sqlQuery, LEN(@sqlquery) - 1)
```

This will remove trailing spaces and the last character before that.